# Calling out the Sum of a Data I Made

Tags: function, python-2.7, for-loop, sum

I am working with a text file and need to call out the sum found from my last column of data [4] that I have made. I have done everything I need for the last column and have used total += square to add the first value in row one with the next value in row two and so on till I hit my 100th row in my text file. Now I need to be able to take my sum that I want in my 100 row and store it as a variable. How can I go about calling it out?

```
fullPath = open("localzscoretest.txt", "r") #Where I have our the current table located
import math

def globalchiSquare(fullPath):
    for line in fullPath:
        line = line.strip() #Strip it
        lines = line.split(',') #split it
        rows = lines[1:] #keeping the numbers
        rows = map(float, rows) #getting my numbers in the .txt ready for the equation
        square = (rows[4]**2) #squared the z score column
        total += square
        print total      
globalchiSquare(fullPath)
```

Comment: Please remove everything from your post that has nothing to do with the problem. What's the problem? Getting the sum of the elements in a list?

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried to have as much information in there as I could. I am looking to try and save my sum as a variable. I have a text file of 100 rows and need to find the sum of it. I used total += sqaure in my script to add the first value in row one with the next value in row two and so on and my sum that I want is in the 100 row. But I don't know how to call it out from the other rows and save it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Give `globalchiSquare` a `readlines()` method in order to iterate.

In the function do

```
def globalchiSquare(fullPath):
    for line in fullPath.readlines():
        . . .
```

You should also keep your variables clear. When you say `lines`, it seems like you are saying that there are multiple--`rows`, too.

Just make it more simple and include the sum.

```
def globalchiSquare(fullPath):
    total = 0
    for line in fullPath.readlines(): # readlines() method
        line = line.strip() # cut off ends
        line = line.split(',') # create list
        row = line[1:] # create row from line
        row = map(float,row) # convert to floats
        square = row[4]**2 # find square
        print 'square',square
        total += square
        print 'total',total
    return total

my_var = globalchiSquare(fullPath)
print my_var # should give total
```

EDIT: The `return` statement allows you to store the value of `total`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and it worked out perfectly! But how can I store the very last line? That is the total (sum) I am looking for and will need it as I advance with my script.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
square = (rows[4]**2) #squared the z score column
```

to be

```
square += (rows[4]**2) #squared the z score column
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I get this error when adding the + to my script: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'square' referenced before assignment"